# What techniques and tools are available to help debug SiteKiosk clients?

Tags: debugging

I am responsible for the maintenance and development of some SiteKiosk client machines.  Currently, we are running version 6 of the software, and do not have an intention of upgrading in the near future.

I have a demo machine where I can turn on whatever functionality I want to facilitate my debugging, but the embedded browser in SiteKiosk supports a very limited set of functionality.  What's more, it enables custom Javascript objects, that prevent me from attempting to view my code in a non-embedded browser.

Anyway, what techniques do you use to code against this browswer?

Answer (score 2):

You can run that software on your development machine and turn off all protection features (window management, keyboard filter, shell replacement etc.), enable the debug window and then using the SiteKiosk.Logfile.Notification() method to print output to the debug window.